# ChefServer how to verify who changed something recently

Tags: logging, chef-infra

In my organization, we have lot of users contribute to the chef server. These users have their workstation configured with individual keys. Now how to keep track if anyone had changed a recipe without bumping the version (or) if anyone changed the environment ? Or a role ?

Comment: See: http://xanzy.io/projects/chef-guard/introduction/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Avoid interacting with the Chef server directly. Establish an automated process that fills the Chef Server based on commits to a version control system (aka. Continuous Delivery and friends).

Further motivation and examples for that can be found in:

- [Cooking with Jenkins](http://www.cryptocracy.com/blog/2014/01/03/cooking-with-jenkins-test-kitchen-and-docker/) by Zachary Stevens
- [Pipeline cookbook](https://github.com/chef-solutions/pipeline) by Chef Solutions
- [Stupid Jenkins Tricks, Part 2: Cookbook Pipelines](http://atomic-penguin.github.io/blog/2014/05/16/stupid-jenkins-tricks-part-2-cookbook-pipelines/) by Eric G. Wolfe

Comment: Thanks @StephenKing, So you mean that there is no way we can find out if we have not implemented the automated process ?

Comment: @DeepakBattu To be complete, if everyone has its own account you can parse the access log files of nginx to know who POSTed what at which time. But this is more a forensic approach than the one described in this answer.